# Notice: Undefined index: enrollment_number in C:\wamp\www\lamp\main.php on line 162

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code. it has been connected to a database, the table is successfully made and the values are successfully entered. The error mentioned in the question is showing when i want to view the table. The error is for both enrollment no. and sub1.

```
$student_academic_details = "CREATE TABLE student_academic_details
    (
        enrollment_number varchar(30),
        sub1 int(2),
        sub2 int(2),
        sub3 int(2)
    )";

echo"<br><br>";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $student_academic_details))
    {
        echo "Table student_academic_details created successfully";
    }
else
    {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

echo"<br><br>";

$row2 = "INSERT INTO student_academic_details VALUES ('009/015', '87', '78', '85')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $row2)) 
    {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $row2 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }



$show = "select * FROM student_personal_details";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $show);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        echo "id: " . $row["enrollment_number"]. " - sub1: " . $row["sub1"]. "<br>";
        }
    }
else
    {
    echo "0 results";
    }
```

Comment: enrollment_number column not exist in your table just check spelling or word

Comment: in this table student_personal_details do you have that field? or mistyped the table name to student_personal_details from student_academic_details

Comment: Thanks a lot... I can't believe my own stupidity

Answer (score 1):

You create table named student_academic_details but selecting from student_personal_details. Probably no field in these table.